# mod_rewrite rule to change url parameter to anchor

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, server

I have to change the URL

**from**: myurl.com/?id=para

**to**: myurl.com/#para

I think it would be best if this is done with mod_rewrite on the server.

Does anyone have a tip for me on what the rule is for this. I have not succeeded so far.

Comment: OK - I now use myurl.com/?id=para#para
It's not so fine, but does what I want to do.

Comment: Does that mean that myurl.com/?id=para#foo works exactly the same?

Comment: Yes, it does the same thing, just looks a bit unusual I think. I need the anchor for a CSS modal and I don't think this URL can be done with rewrite.